# Delete all invalid URLs of an array

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3

I would like to delete all invalid URLs of an array. (e.g. v.1.1, version1.2.00, the.area.0a)

```
var myArray:Array = new Array("v.1.1", "example.com", "www.example.com","http://example.com","version1.2.00","http://www.example.com","the.area.0a","http://example.com/helloworld123");
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 parts of the problem. One is that you want to [filter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter%28%29) your array. It would create a new array, but you can assign the return from `filter` back to `myArray`. The function that you pass to `filter` function can use [String.match](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match%28%29) to match whatever type of regular expression you deem fit for a valid url (this matching is the second part of the problem).